# Encoding issue with mysql when using UCS2

Tags: mysql, encoding

I am trying to import one big csv file encoded in UCS2-Big Indian into a mysql table.

This is the mysql code:

```
DROP TABLE if exists PAPERS; 

CREATE TABLE `PAPERS` (
ID_RESEARCHER VARCHAR(20),
PAPER_ACCESSOR_NUMBER VARCHAR(20),
  primary key(ID_RESEARCHER,PAPER_ACCESSOR_NUMBER)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2;

load data local infile '...dump_all_papers_test_2.csv' 
into table PAPERS
CHARACTER SET ucs2
fields terminated by '\t' enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n' 
(ID_RESEARCHER, PAPER_ACCESSOR_NUMBER);
```

And the content of csv (format ucs-2 Big Indian, said by notepad++)

```
"100"   "A1974U626600001"
"100"   "A1974U626600001"
"100"   "A1974U626600001"
```

A copy of csv sample:

http://pastebin.com/HMssuxCf

And the error is:

```
1 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s):
1265 Data truncated for column 'ID_RESEARCHER' at row 1
1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 2
```

What is happening here?

The action only fills the first field. Is not mysql support ucs2?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

The solution is in the documentation:

Note that it is currently not possible to load data files that use the ucs2 character set.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html